# Is it possible for DOM structure to be different than that from the response when visualized through Chrome's Inspect Element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, tags

I personally don't think it is possible, but, HTML that I am getting from the response is something like this:
(center tag, then table tag inside it, then two table tags inside)

```
.
.
<center> 
    <table>
        <table>
        <table>
.
.
```

but, when I am viewing it in "Elements" tab of Inspect Element (Chrome), it is something like this:
(center tag, then three table tags inside it)

```
.
.
<center> 
    <table>
    <table>
    <table>
.
.
```

Is it possible or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: The DOM can be manipulated at will through js or editing through the inspector. Also the browser will attempt to error correct invalid html syntax when it is added to the DOM, eg a table tag directly inside a table tag is invalid. So yes once html is added to the DOM it can have a different structure than the the html text that you used to add.

Comment: The `<center>` tag has been deprecated for a **long** time, nobody should be using it for anything.

Comment: As said @PatrickEvans, browsers try to "fix" invalid HTML. They don't know how to renderize invalid HTML, so they try to fix it. But each browser can take different ways in order to do this. That's why is so important to respect HTML spec when authoring an HTML document.

Comment: Oh Ok... thanks a lot everyone... I get it now...